# C++ Unusual double free corruption error (copy constructor doesn't work)

Tags: c++, debugging, g++

I'm a student and I've been asked to "replicate" (sort of) the vector class. Obviously, the infamous "double free corruption" occured. I've been thaught the three rules (maybe not so well), and I can't find the error.

Vettore.h

```
#ifndef vettore_h_
#define vettore_h_

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

class Vettore {

   protected:
      unsigned int _N;
      double * _v;
      void Quicksort(unsigned int primo, unsigned int ultimo);
      void Scambia (int a, int b);

   public:
      Vettore ();
      Vettore (int N);
      Vettore (int N, char* nomefile);
      Vettore (const Vettore& v);
      void SetComponent (int i, double x);
      void AddComponent (double x);
      double GetComponent (int i) const;
      void Print () const;
      void Print (char* nomefile) const;
      void Sort();
      int GetN() const;
      Vettore& operator=(const Vettore & vetty);
      ~Vettore();   
};

#endif
```

Vettore.c

```
#include "Vettore.h"

//Default Constructor

Vettore :: Vettore () {

   _N=0;
   _v=NULL;

};

//N Constructor

Vettore :: Vettore (int N) {

   _N=N;
   _v=new double [_N];

   for (int i=0; i<_N; i++)
      _v[i]=0;
};

//N file-taken constructor

Vettore :: Vettore (int N, char* nomefile) {

   _N=N;
   _v=new double [_N];

   std::ifstream input;
   input.open(nomefile);

   double dato;

   input>>dato;

   for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
      _v[i]=dato;
      input>>dato;
   };

   input.close();

};

//Copyconstructor

Vettore :: Vettore (const Vettore& V) {

   _N=V.GetN();

   _v=new double [_N];

   for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
      _v[i]=V.GetComponent(i);


};

//Destructor

Vettore::~Vettore(){

   delete[] _v;

};

//Set Component

void Vettore :: SetComponent (int i, double x) {

   if (i>_N) {
      std::cout<<"errore!"<<std::endl;
      return ;
   };


   _v[i]=x;

};

//Get Component

double Vettore :: GetComponent (int i) const {

   if (i>_N){
      std::cout<<"errore!"<<std::endl;
      return 0;
   };

   return _v[i];
};

//Add Component 

void Vettore :: AddComponent (double x) {

   double* a=new double [_N+1];

   for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
      a[i]=_v[i];

   a[_N]=x;

   _v=a;
   _N=_N+1;
   a=NULL;
   delete [] a;

};

//Print

void Vettore :: Print () const {

   std::cout<<"Il vettore ha: "<<_N<<" componenti."<<std::endl;

   for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
      std::cout<<_v[i]<<std::endl;

};

//Print file

void Vettore :: Print (char* nomefile) const {
   std::ofstream output;
   output.open(nomefile);

   output<<_N;

   for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
      output<<_v[i]<<std::endl;

   output.close();

};


//Get _N

int Vettore :: GetN () const {

   return _N;

};

//Operatore di Assegnazione

Vettore & Vettore::operator =(const Vettore& vetty){

   _N=vetty.GetN();
   _v=new double [_N];

   for(int n; n<_N; n++)
      _v[n]=vetty._v[n];

   return *this;
};



//Algoritmo Quicksort

void Vettore :: Sort (){
    Quicksort(0,GetN()-1);
};

void Vettore :: Quicksort (unsigned int primo, unsigned int ultimo) {

    if(ultimo-primo<=1){
       if (GetComponent(primo)>GetComponent(ultimo)) Scambia(primo, ultimo);
       return;
    }

    double pivot= GetComponent(int((primo+ultimo)/2));
    unsigned int basso= primo, alto=ultimo;
    while(basso < alto) {

        while (GetComponent(basso)<pivot) basso++;
        while (GetComponent(alto)>pivot) alto--;
        if(basso<alto) { Scambia(basso,alto); basso++;};
    };
    Quicksort(primo, basso-1);
    Quicksort(basso, ultimo);
};

void Vettore :: Scambia(int a, int b){

    double k;
    k=_v[a];
    _v[a]=_v[b];
    _v[b]=k;
};
```

main example

```
#include "Vettore.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argv, char** argc) {

   Vettore A(10);

   Vettore B(10, argc[1]);

   Vettore C(B);

   C.SetComponent(2, 3);

   B.AddComponent(12.5);

   cout<<A.GetComponent(3)<<" "<<A.GetN()<<endl;

   B.Sort();

   B.Print();

   C.Print(argc[2]);

   A.~Vettore();
   B.~Vettore();
   C.~Vettore();

   return 0;
}
```

The strange thing is that the destructor is called (I checked via couts in the destructor) three times; an other odd thing is that I cannot clearly locate the source of the error, since sometimes the AddComponent gives me problems (but not always), while the Copyconstructor seems to always give me problems (in other words, if I eliminate the C vector initialized with the copyconstructor, it doesn't give me an error).

Comment: And you added the C tag - why??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  When your question is about C++ and constructors, please do not dual-tag it with both the [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags — that will frequently incur people's wrath.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_N`) or contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> A.~Vettore();
> B.~Vettore();
> C.~Vettore();
> ```

This is the source of your error. Beginners rarely, if ever, need to explicitly call the destructor for an object. The destructor is automatically called for your object `A`, `B`, and `C` when they go out of scope.

Comment: Also, the assignment operator has a memory leak (the _v is assigned but any previously allocated memory is not freed). When fixing that, take in the account the possibility of self-assignment as well.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that! :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `Add Component`

```
_v=a;
_N=_N+1;
a=NULL;
delete [] a;
```

The correct way to achieve this is:

```
_N = _N + 1;
delete[] _v;
_v = a;
```

<strike>Or you will delete `_v` twice when the destructor of the object is called, explicitly or implicitly.</strike>

Comment: The last sentence is wrong. As written, the code deletes nothing; _v is not even deleted once, nevermind twice. That's a memory leak and your fix is correct, but it has nothing to do with the double-free problem.

Comment: Thanks  rici, totally agree LOL.

Comment: Thank you very much! But why eliminate also the "delete [] a"?

Comment: `a` is the new array containing the old elements and the new one `x`, so this array is just you want to keep. After copying all elements from the old array you should delete the old `_v` and reassign it to point to the new array.